# How to sort the order in which to declare variables

Tags: vba, variables, declaration

I'm writing a mid-size script in vba with ~40 subs and one of my subs contains >60 variables now which makes it somewhat hard to keep track of all declared variables. (Do I have a variable for this or that already? Should I maybe recycle variables for multi-purpose, did I declare variables that are no longer used, etc.)

Right now the declarations are sorted historically which means when I declared a new variable I put the line below all other declarations, but that does not seem like good coding practice.

Factors that come into my mind are by data type (used types are Boolean, Long, Single, Double, String, Range, Object and Variant including arrays of different data types. These again I could sort by size, alphabetically, purpose, etc.), alphabetically, historically (which I don't like anymore), by 1st appearance in the sub (which would need most maintenance work), by purpose (i.e. group the variables i, j and k together) and grouped by in which parts of the sub they will be used. (lower half, middle, bottom, etc.)

So I wonder as a reader of my code which order you would like most and to what degree I should consider grouping the variables by their appearance in the sub.
Are there any standardized good practices for order of variable declaration?
Maybe some examples to study?

Greetings, andy01q

PS: Note that I would usually go like "Dim a, b, c as Long" in other languages, but since vba turns out to declare a and b as variant with that line of code I decided to give each variable its own line (to avoid errors in which I accidentally declared variables as Variant between other variables that all have the same type.) which avoided errors but resulted in the given mess.

Comment: Maybe you should break up that sub into several smaller subs.  Sixty variables is a terrible code smell.

Comment: It's going to be split into 12-20 smaller subs in a later construction phase but would be very bothersome to do right now. Nevertheless thank you for the comment, your point is of course valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some ways it doesn't matter what you do as long as it is reasonable and you do it consistently. This is one of the things which I gleaned from book "Code Complete" by Steve McConnell. This book contains excellent suggestions about things like variable naming, code layout, comment style, etc. My VBA became much more polished after reading that book (which mostly uses C and Pascal for examples but is easily applied to just about any languages).

I wrote a sub to expand `Dim` lines:

```
Sub expand(dimLine As String)
    Dim fragments As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, myType As String
    Dim last As Variant
    Dim expanded As String

    fragments = Split(dimLine, ",")
    n = UBound(fragments)
    last = Split(Trim(fragments(n)))
    myType = last(UBound(last))
    For i = 0 To n - 1 'excludes last fragment
        expanded = expanded & IIf(i = 0, "", ",") & fragments(i) & " As " & myType
    Next i
    expanded = expanded & IIf(n > 0, ",", "") & fragments(n)
    Debug.Print expanded
End Sub
```

If you type `expand "Dim a, b, c as Long"` in the Immediate Window it expands to

```
Dim a As Long, b As Long, c as Long
```

which can be pasted directly into your code. Having written this, I never found it particularly useful -- but then again I've never had a sub with >60 variables. Maybe it could help you.

On Edit: `expand` can be modified to copy to the clipboard instead of (or in addition to) printing to the immediate window. To do so:

1) Add a reference to `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library` to your project

2) Include the declaration `Dim clip As New DataObject`

3) Replace (or supplement) the line `Debug.Print expanded` by the two lines

```
clip.SetText expanded
clip.PutInClipboard
```

Then the expanded declaration is ready to paste into the code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The book you mentioned suggests to declare variables right before they are used to minimize their span and live time. A friend that I also asked suggested to give variables prefixes corresponding to their name. (like strname, lngcounter, rngsearchrange etc.) I'll rethink all that and then make my decisions.

Comment: *corresponding to their type

Comment: @andy01q  I tend to like my variables defined at the beginning of a sub or function so I always know where to go to find the declaration -- but my coding to style is to have a lot of small functions/subs rather than a few big ones, so I seldom encounter the situation where my use of a variable is too far from its declaration. As far as prefixes goes, sounds like you are referring to some variation of *Hungarian Notation*. Joel Spolsky (one of the two cocreators of Stack Overflow) has a long but nice blog post on it: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html